# wsimport with authentication and certificateexception

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ssl-certificate, soap-client

Am new to SOAP and am trying to run wsimport command to generate the stubs so that i can call the related services. I have the wsdl url and to access this I would need to authenticate. 
So i tried below command to resolve authentication issue:

> wsimport -Xauthfile C:\auth.txt -keep http://example.com/test?wsdl -s
>   c:\path\to\source\

However when i launch the server url in browser, it complains about the "site is not secure" and I started facing certificateexception after authentication was resolved.

List of things i tried:

1. Did Google and got to know that adding the certificate to cacerts keystore in

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts "

would solve certificate issue.

2. Used keytool command to add the certificate to keystore. below is the command and it is failing with illegal option.

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias aliasname -file cert.cer
>   -keystore 
>       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts
>
> ```
> Illegal option:  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
> ```

Any help appreciated in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a space in the keystore path.

Try typing the keystore path within quotations.

Comment: thanks for the help. It helped me add the certificate to cacerts. But i still end up getting [ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present  [ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.


        Failed to parse the WSDL.. Any help here?

Comment: Since it's a different problem you should search for it, and if you don't find a solution, ask a new question here.

Comment: Have asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454241/wsimport-with-certificateexceptoin